# What is the adjective/verb describing someone who is repeatedly explaining itself in an argument when rest of the people already got the point

Tags: verbs, adjectives

I don't remember if it is adjective describing a person or action, but I had come across an adjective describing someone who is constantly reapiting itself when trying expalining something. It occures often in heated argument.

**Edit.1**:
It might have been a verb actually. It describes someone or something when one person is in argument and start explaining itself over and over again, when rest on the involved people already got the point.

Comment: I would have said 'stuttering' or 'stammering' but those aren't adjectives, they're verbs. Is there a sentence you can give for context?

Comment: It's noone of your propositions. Actually it might have been a verb. I came across it when watching highly competitive e-sport player who was in argument and started to extensively explaining himself and reapiting everything over and over again in a process, when everyone already was understanding his point.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Stammering is when a person finds it difficult to get their words out, not when they are deliberately repeating themself.

Comment: **Bullheaded** describes anyone who is particularly stubborn, but it could be applied to someone in an argument.

Comment: Please don't add an answer to your question. If you have an answer, you can post one in the answer box, as you have done. Also, please don't close the question. The Q&A is meant to be useful to future visitors as well.

Answer (score 1):

"dwelling on" or "fixated on"

> Eg: There's no point dwelling on what could have happened, we lost and that's that.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one adjective: to be ***over-apologetic***. And I do not mean it in the sense of a [psychological disorder](https://theswaddle.com/why-some-people-over-apologize-and-others-never-do/#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9COver%2Dapologizing%20can%20stem%20from,to%20over%2Dapologize%20is%20OCD.), but simply in the sense of overdoing it in a particular situation.

But I might be cheating, it may be counted as 2 words.

As for verbs I am thinking of

> [going on and on about something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/goes+on+and+on+about): babble, overemphasise, mumble on, harp on, insist or persist

I particularly like ***[exasperate](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/exasperate/synonyms)***, but it maybe only a connotation of what you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not it. I'm pretty sure it was one word.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: I found it. Sorry, after all there were two words. I was looking for "sperging out", but thank you for your input.

Comment: careful, it is [_**sperg out**_](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sperg%20out) . Your context was a bit misleading, though.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that.

Answer (score 0):

The word I was looking for was "sperging out".

From ubandictionary.com

> When someone goes on a long, in-depth, overly elaborate explanation
> long after everyone already gets the point, but will not end.
> You get the point, but the person continues to explain their point,
> and often times stutters and stammers whilst doing so.

After all, I missed some point when explaining the word.

Comment: Just to put it out there, that's an offensive term. It's a derisive reference to Asperger's Syndrome, a form of mild autism. I wouldn't recommend adding it to your vocabulary.

Comment: I see. That's why I couldn't find equivalent for that in my mother language.